# difference between override init and required init? - swift

Tags: ios, swift

I sometimes see a view made like this where there is the same setup() function in two different init methods. What is the difference between the init methods and why is the same setup() being called in both..?

```
class BigButton: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }

    fileprivate func setup() {
        // set up stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: @holex how about super lazy

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`override init(frame: CGRect)` is used when you create the view (in this case the button) programmatically.

`required init?(coder: NSCoder)` is used when the view is created from storyboard/xib.

since the latter is required you must implement its body. However if you are not going to create the button manually the first one is not required and can be omitted

setup is called in both because however you choose to create the button you want to setup its custom behavior so it will work as you intended it to

Answer (score 13):

When you `override` an initializer such as `init(frame: CGRect)`, you do it against a **designated** initializer, i.e. the principal initializer responsible for creating an object programmatically. According to rules, you must call `super.init` **before** performing any additional init actions.

Required initializers, on the other hand, are not the same as designated.

> **Required Initializers**
>
> Write the required modifier before the definition of a class
>   initializer to indicate that every subclass of the class must
>   implement that initializer.
>
> You must also write the required modifier before every subclass
>   implementation of a required initializer, to indicate that the
>   initializer requirement applies to further subclasses in the chain.
>   You do not write the override modifier when overriding a required
>   designated initializer.
>
> <sub>**Source**: [Apple Documentation On Initializers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_335)</sub>

You implement required initializer regardless of your will when you make a subclass if original class has that initializer marked as required. Commonly, you are not supposed to call it directly to create an object, although in certain cases you do. Required initializers are marked required to comply with several, well, requirements. For instance,
`required init?(coder: NSCoder)` is called in several cases. One case: when the view is created from IB. Another case - when an object is created, or rather, unarchived (that is called deserialization) manually. In fact, when you put that object onto a ViewController's view (for example), that object is also *unarchived*, i.e. gets all its properties loaded and set.

Obviously, when you make a subclass of some view, you are supposed to make it support this interface, which provides deserialization capability (in case it is sometime used from Interface Builder or either). This is why it is `required`.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for when I googled "override init vs required init swift". I already knew what each of these methods did, but I didn't know why the first one uses "override" and the second one "required".

Answer (score 2):

If you're using such class both in ***Interface Builder*** somewhere and ***programmatically*** some elsewhere, and the setup stuff had to be done no matter how you use the class, it's easier to write the `init()` like this.

`init(NSCoder:)` is called automatically when you put the button in .nib or storyboard, the compiler know exactly the frame of the view so the `init(CGRect:)` is not necessary. On the contrary, you usually use `init(CGRect:)` when creating views with codes, you want to make sure the `setup()` is executed during both initialization processes, thus you put `setup()` in both initialization functions.